# Exclude resource paths from Jersey application.wadl?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

Jersey provides a dynamic wadl at /application.wadl. In my case, I have both internal-only and external paths exposed in my application. I want to exclude the internal apis from the dynamic wadl generation.

Is there some configuration to tell Jersey to ignore certain paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding it myself with something like this:

```
@Context
protected UriInfo uriInfo;

@Context
protected WadlApplicationContext wadlContext;

@GET
@Path("/wadl")
@Produces({"application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response wadl() {

        // most of this is lifted from org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource
        try {
            boolean detailedWadl = WadlUtils.isDetailedWadlRequested(uriInfo);
            String lastModified = new SimpleDateFormat(WadlResource.HTTPDATEFORMAT).format(new Date());
            ApplicationDescription applicationDescription = wadlContext.getApplication(uriInfo, detailedWadl);
            Application application = applicationDescription.getApplication();
            application.getResources().stream().findFirst().get().getResource().removeIf(resource -> !resource.getPath().startsWith("/public_api"));
            ByteArrayInputStream wadl = marshal(application);
            return Response.ok(wadl).header("Last-modified", lastModified).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ProcessingException("Error generating WADL", e);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Jersey documentation: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/wadl.html
You have three ways:

1. Setting in web.xml will disable the whole wadl
   jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl=true
2. Use of @ExtendedResource
   annotation will not display annotated method/class in default wadl,
   but only in extended one.
3. According to 17.2, you can also override
   default wadl with your own using Jersey itself.